# Spring 4.3.25.RELEASE OAuth2 Configuration Problem

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am working on a system that uses Spring 4.3.25.RELEASE and xml based configuration. I need to integrate with another system using OAuth2, and therefore trying to configure the system as an OAuth2 Client, but it's proving difficult to find examples and documentation.

I can redirect to the IdP ok, but on return I am seeing this error:

> Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was required but no state
> could be found

This is the configuration I have in place, which is obviously incomplete. Can you please help me identify what is missing?

Thanks.

```
<custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>
<custom-filter ref="oauth2AuthenticationFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>

...

<oauth:client id="oauth2ClientFilter" />
<beans:bean id="oauth2AuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="defaultFilterProcessesUrl" value="/oauth2/callback"/>
    <beans:property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplate"/>
</beans:bean>

<oauth:rest-template id="restTemplate" resource="oauth2Token"/>
<oauth:resource id="oauth2Token" 
    type="authorization_code" 
    client-id="my-client-id"
    client-secret="my-client-secret"
    access-token-uri="https://http://myurl/token" 
    user-authorization-uri="http://myurl/authorize"/>
```

Comment: Have you checked the callback sent from the other system to confirm it is sending back the state param? Spring will include it in the authorization request, but maybe your client is not sending it back.

Comment: My application is the client.